# Change position of arrow icon based on sort

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, columnsorting

Hi my sorting is done via the backend, I need to reflect it in the UI with React.

**I'm looking to achieve this:**

1. Arrow position is defaulted to pointing down when page loads (no sort is occurring at this stage)
2. Click on Arrow this will point upwards sorting table results as ascending
3. Click on Arrow again this will point downwards sorting table results as descending

**Right now my code does this:**

1. Arrow position is defaulted to pointing upwards when page loads
2. Click on Arrow it changes to down arrow and sorts table results as descending
3. Click on Arrow again it changes to upwards and sorts table results as ascending

   ```
   import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
   import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
   import styled from 'styled-components';
   import { FaIcon } from './icons';

   const HeaderWrapper = styled.div`
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
   `;

   const Div = styled.div`
     font-weight: bold;
   `;
   const Icon = styled(FaIcon)`
     font-size: 16px;
   `;

   const TableHeader = ({ title, field, getSortedJobs }) => {
     const [ascending, setAscending] = useState(null);

     const nullCheck = () => {
       if (!ascending) return 'desc';
       if (ascending === 'asc') return 'desc';
       return 'asc';
     };

     const positionArrow = () => {
       if (!ascending) return ['far', 'chevron-up'];
       if (ascending === 'asc') return ['far', 'chevron-up'];
       return ['far', 'chevron-down'];
     };

     const sortBy = () => {
       setAscending(nullCheck());
     };

     useEffect(() => {
       if (ascending) getSortedJobs(field, ascending);
     }, [ascending]);
     return (
       <HeaderWrapper onClick={() => sortBy()}>
         <Div>{title}</Div>
         <Icon icon={positionArrow()} />
       </HeaderWrapper>
     );
   };

   TableHeader.propTypes = {
     title: PropTypes.string,
     field: PropTypes.array,
     getSortedJobs: PropTypes.func,
   };

   TableHeader.defaultProps = {
     title: '',
     field: [],
     getSortedJobs: () => {},
   };

   export default TableHeader;
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but I think you'll need to change this line in function `positionArrow`:

```
if (!ascending) return ['far', 'chevron-up'];
```

to:

```
if (!ascending) return ['far', 'chevron-down'];
```

since `ascending` will be `null`/falsey and you want the arrow to be pointing down to begin with.

---

Then I think you should also change this line in function `nullCheck`:

```
if (!ascending) return 'desc';
```

to:

```
if (!ascending) return 'asc';
```

since `ascending` will the `null`/falsey to begin with (i.e. `desc` initially) and so the next value needs to be `asc`.

---

Sidenote: Since you want the same behaviour for when `ascending` is `null` or `desc`, you could also re-write the functions as:

```
const positionArrow = () => {
  return ['far', 'asc' === ascending ? 'chevron-up' : 'chevron-down'];
};

const sortBy = () => {
  setAscending(prev => 'asc' === prev ? 'desc' : 'asc');
};
```

This would also allow you to get rid of function `nullCheck` (if you're not using it anywhere other than `sortBy`).

Answer (score 0):

You should set the value of `ascending` here so when next you call `nullCheck()` you won't always get `desc` as the sorting value.

```
const nullCheck = () => {
    ascending = (!ascending || ascending === 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';

    return ascending;
};
```

You can join your conditions for `if` statements

```
const positionArrow = () => {
    if (!ascending || ascending === 'asc') return ['far', 'chevron-up'];
    return ['far', 'chevron-down'];
};
```

Comment: I also liked yours, but the other answer was easier.